# How to clear the Overlay using GWT

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I have a class which I used to overlay rectangles on maps. But I am not able to figure out how to remove the previous overlay's to draw new rectangles if a new set of results are provided to my **displayOnMap method**.

To provide more insight on the **draw** method. It takes in PlotSetOutput as an argument which contains centers and each center contains a set of lat/long co-ordinates. Hence the logic for looping over it and creating lat/long bounds and assigning it to rectangle objects.

```java
public class displayOnMap extends Composite {

    private final VerticalPanel pWidget;
    private MapWidget mapWidget;
    private static Rectangle rectangle;
    private RectangleOptions rectOpts;
    private static final LatLng USCENTER = LatLng.newInstance(33.68,-116.17);

    public displayOnMap(PlotSetOutput result) {
        pWidget = new VerticalPanel();
        initWidget(pWidget);
        draw(result);
    }

    private void draw(PlotSetOutput result) {
        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.newInstance();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(USCENTER);
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mapWidget = new MapWidget(mapOpts);
        pWidget.add(mapWidget);
        mapWidget.setSize("800px", "800px");

        ArrayList<Centers> listOfCenters = new ArrayList<Centers>();

        List<ResultClusterPlots> finalCluster = result.getFinalcluster();

        int totalNumberOfClusters = result.getTotalNumberOfClusters();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfClusters; i++) {
            listOfCenters.add(i, new Centers());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < finalCluster.size(); j++) {
            Centers p = listOfCenters.get(finalCluster.get(j).getClusterID()-1);

            LatLng ne = LatLng.newInstance(finalCluster.get(j).getLatitude()
                    .get(0), finalCluster.get(j).getLongitude().get(0));

            LatLng sw = LatLng.newInstance(finalCluster.get(j).getLatitude()
                    .get(1), finalCluster.get(j).getLongitude().get(1));

            p.setLatLongArr(LatLngBounds.newInstance(ne,sw));
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < listOfCenters.size(); k++) {
            ArrayList<LatLngBounds> ltlgBound = listOfCenters.get(k).getLatLongArr();
            String color = getRandomColor();
            for (int l = 0; l < ltlgBound.size(); l++) {
                rectOpts = RectangleOptions.newInstance();
                rectOpts.setStrokeColor("#FF0000");
                rectOpts.setStrokeOpacity(0.3);
                rectOpts.setStrokeWeight(2);
                rectOpts.setFillColor(color);
                rectOpts.setFillOpacity(0.35);
                rectOpts.setMap(mapWidget);
                rectOpts.setBounds(ltlgBound.get(l));
                rectangle = Rectangle.newInstance(rectOpts);
                rectangle.setMap(mapWidget);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Output when the method (displayOnMap) is invoked for the first time. Everything works fine.** 
[image]

**Output when the displayOnMap method is called with a second query.**

[image]

I tried to do **rectangle.setMap(null); pWidget.removeFromParent();** but I kept getting the same result.

Comment: I tried the source but it is missing some classes. Could you provide a complete example with all the classes so I could test it in the showcase?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the only way I could hide / delete / show the overlays was through the OverlayCompleteMapEvent. 
As I understand it isn't possible to get a hook to an overlay before it is completed, once it is completed the only way to get a hook on it is handling "OverlayCompleteMapEvent" event. I used a list to store the Overlays and then I could hide/show/delete them.